# Recover files without an extension after deleting them with a BASH command

Tags: bash, data-recovery

Last night, I used exiftool to batch rename a collection of .mov files. Some of the files were renamed as required, but many of them were left without an extension.

I think the required EXIF tag that I used in the exiftool command was missing from some the files, resulting in ~140 .mov files renamed in a timestamp format without an extension.

Rather than manually appending .mov to each file, I searched Google for a script to automate the process. I adapted an example and executed it (*+0100 refers to common string at the end of all the target files):

```
$ for i in *+0100; do mv "$i" "`basename $i *+0100`.mov"; done
```

For some reason, ~140 files disappeared and I was left with a single file with a .mov extension. Not quite what I was expecting!

I searched the partition with `photorec`, but I haven't been able to recover the files. Is there any other way I may be able to recover them? These particular family videos were some of the few that I had not yet backed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [DataRevovery](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery).

Next time, when you do such loops always add `echo` as a first command. After you see what you are about to do, remove the `echo`, and rerun. It's a common mistake - sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, Michał. I will be more careful in future.

Answer (score 0):

When I try that command I just get an error with basename, I think is was meant to be:

```
for i in *+0100; do mv "$i" "`basename $i`.mov"; done
```

I don't think they can be recovered, but you can [try extundelete](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/).